# OpenGL GLSL vector of sampler2D

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders

If im trying to create an obj. file loader in c++ and draw it with opengl i need to use multiple textures in the fragment shader.I know i can just use:

```
`uniform sampler2D Texture1` 
`uniform sampler2D Texture2` 
`uniform sampler2D Texture3` 
`uniform sampler2D Texture4`
```

But i think there must be an elegant way to do it.Like a vector of samplers or something.Im asking this because i dont want to declare `n` textures in my fragment shader and type `n` if's where i test which texture i should use for the current fragment.It just looks ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, 3d textures. It is the same as a 2d, except it has layers of textures on top if each other. You sample it with `texture3d(Sampler2d sampler, vec3 texture coord)`
You still need zo create these, but you only load 1 uniform integer.

To bind a 3d texture, you bind the GL_TEXTURE_3D instead of a texture_2d

Comment: Also, note that you **can** use z positions other than 1, 2, 3 etc, but if you set the texture filter mod to  liner, it will interpolate between them. Nearest does the same thing as round()